# Errors I face when I knit a RMarkdown file

Tags: r-markdown, knitr

When I knit my RMarkdown file, I face this error:

> Sorry, but C:\Users\Narges.BT\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
> ! The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going again:
> ! C:\Users\Narges.BT\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\pdflatex.log
> ! pdflatex: major issue: So far, you have not checked for MiKTeX updates.
> Error: LaTeX failed to compile trial.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See trial.log for more info.
> Execution halted

I installed and updated MicTex console properly and have tried all the solutions that have been provided earlier.

Does anyone have any idea of what actions should I take?

Comment: You may try TinyTeX instead of MikTeX: https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/install-latex.html

Comment: Try another latex program like Yihui suggests. Also when you install rmarkdown, do `install.packages(rmarkdown, dep =TRUE)` which should push extra dependencies to be installed. Did you install miktex as admin on your pc? Try running windows updates as wel